# Convert int values (1,0) to boolean using FromQueryAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this API method:

```
  [HttpGet("foo")]
  public IActionResult Foo([FromQuery] bool parameter)
  {
    // ...
  }
```

And I know I can call my method like this and it will work:

```
.../foo?parameter=true
```

But I also want to support numeric values 0 and 1 and call my method like this:

```
.../foo?parameter=1
```

But when I try, I get this exception inside `System.Private.CoreLib`

```
System.FormatException: 'String '1' was not recognized as a valid Boolean.'
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result? Did you get an error or a 404 or something else?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Igor yes, sorry, I did try. I've updated my answer to explain the error that I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default `ModelBinder` didn't support `1` to `bool`, we can try to create our own binding logic by implementing `IModelBinder` interface.

```
public class BoolModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).FirstValue;

        if (int.TryParse(value, out var intValue)) {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(intValue == 1);

        } else if (bool.TryParse(value, out var boolValue)) {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(boolValue);

        } else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(false);
        } 
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

then we can use `ModelBinderAttribute` to assign our `BoolModelBinder` type as this binder.

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
public IActionResult Foo([ModelBinder(typeof(BoolModelBinder))] bool parameter)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I actually made a generic ModelBinder that I can apply to any request class, so all the booleans always support 1 and 0 as values.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to change an input parameter type to string

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
  public IActionResult Foo([FromQuery] string parameter)
  {
    if( parameter=="true" || parameter=="1") ....
    else if( parameter=="false" || parameter=="0") ....
    else ....
  }
```

Comment: Or simply Function Overloads.